# Assigning a new property and value to an existing object

Tags: typescript

I want to assign a new property to an existing object. I'd prefer to not have to make an interface or type. Here is the error I am receiving:

```
Property 'completion_date' does not exist on type '{ course_status: string; completion_percentage: string; }'.
```

```
const courseCompletionStatus = (completionPercentage: string) => {
  
  const courseStatus = {
    course_status: 'in progress',
    completion_percentage: completionPercentage
  }
    if (completionPercentage === '100%') courseStatus.completion_date = new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0).toString()

  return courseStatus
  
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKCuAnCBTAwiAtgBwDYqgEtwBlKAQynghgF4YAKUHfI8ABRUWBTAoHMUALhjREhMPwCUdAHwwA3gCgYMFXHDQNSVGUrU6i9aoTIUAfWj6IIgOQSY2RCH6IUECLYA0xjSwLEYObYXDx85IIizHgBHKG8AijqAL6+hABmjNGsgZzcCREodLT0tgCMAAwVAKS2Mqa6FFQQAHTZsUEAJpRF9GAoAO4wACI9DFItqFAAqgAqaAASIDoMFV4waxvrFRNQIGTikuNK6m5UiGDaZnrN6krJQA)

What would be the best way to create the property and assign the value when the `completion_percentage` is `'100%'`? I only want to include `completion_date` when the `completion_percentage` is `'100%'`.

Comment: 1. create a type that accurately describes your intended object 2. Use the type

Comment: "*I'd prefer to not have to make an interface or type*" why?

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those questions like "My toenails are getting too long. How can I make them shorter? I'd prefer not to use a toenail clipper."  Before we start coming up with crazy workarounds for clipping toenails without a toenail clipper (e.g., a bandsaw with "assertion function" scrawled on the side), we'd really like to understand the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be creating the property `completion_date` anywhere in `courseStatus`. It will need to be declared first, if you want it to be optional you will have to use something like an interface. You can declare your `courseStatus` object as an interface and declare  `completion_date` as an optional value.

[Here is an example of how you could do this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQewK5QM4QMphxgbbIDeAUMqpjhAPraHGkBcyTUoA5gDRU0AtgAcANhDDA0IesOhJwcbinace-auhHjJ0+gBMiEAPzJVYLiG4UAvhQroQTGllwBhNNolSQBIiWQAXmQACi0xb2kABXkIRWVzS24ASiCAPnIBAUdndFd8ZgD2PLo-FiDM6k1aXEZC7HYAclBkYSg0bigIbGxGjSrwnR9ZWPiIYs8I3RAYqAVCZQE7agFqYBhQwciZ0YWUQIPkRoBGAAZTgFJG1JLcMpIAOi3pgyMKkAgAd2QAESMQ5IPXBgACqABU3AAJGohU68ZBwhHw06AsBoAhJAH2ahdYhQEAuUr1Wz2BzSbBocQPUQdMI1CAeLzTe7YEInc5XZLJMlOSkQam024MyZDaQstlnTnJIA)

**EDIT:**
You could also cast the object to any and assign the property after, however I wouldn't consider this good practise and would suggest using an interface as it provides type checking.

```
const courseCompletionStatus = (completionPercentage: string) => {
  
  const courseStatus  = {
    course_status: 'in progress',
    completion_percentage: completionPercentage
  }
  
    if (completionPercentage === '100%') (courseStatus as any).completion_date = new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0).toString()

  return courseStatus
}
```

Comment: want to assign a new property to an existing object. I'd prefer to not have to make an interface or type.

Answer (score 0):

Either declare a new `type` or `interface` as suggested above, or use an inline type declaration like:

```js
const courseCompletionStatus = (completionPercentage: string) => {
  
  const courseStatus: {
    course_status: string;
    completion_percentage: string;
    completion_date?: string;
  } = {
    course_status: 'in progress',
    completion_percentage: completionPercentage
  }
  
  if (completionPercentage === '100%') courseStatus.completion_date = new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0).toString()

  return courseStatus
  
}
```

Comment: or, if you want to go full bananas and change an existing object with it's own types that you cannot edit, you can always change the assignment (not recommended) to: `(courseStatus as any).completion_date = ...`